# Matlab： readin csv with multiple data types--what is wrong with the code

Tags: matlab, csv

This how my data file looks like(it is a csv, the dilimiter is ','):

```
ID  Date     X  Y   Z
2003    Mon Mar 21 11:01:53 EDT 2016    -0.002261639    -0.002261639    -0.003986359
2003    Mon Mar 21 11:01:54 EDT 2016    0.010383129 0.010383129 0.145069122
2003    Mon Mar 21 11:01:55 EDT 2016    0.082943439 0.082943439 0.022849083
2003    Mon Mar 21 11:01:57 EDT 2016    0.070415497 0.070415497 0.234290123
```

I wanted to read them in using textscan. Here's my code:

```
clear;close all;

fid=fopen('./test.csv');
data = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f %f %f','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
```

I don't understand, why after running the code, 'data' is like:
data =

```
{1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]
```

Then if I print out data{1}{1} or data{1}, the output is: ID.
It seems nothing is stored in data except for the first two headers....

But this code works perfectly in Octave....I'm so confused....Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You should include the delimiters in your example text. The immediate issue is that you're trying to parse the header and make `X` a floating point number. Use `HeaderLines` option to skip the header

Answer (score 0):

%% You could try the code below (adapted from MATLAB Import Tool)

%% Initialize variables.

```
filename = 'your_comma_delimited_file.csv';
delimiter = ',';
startRow = 2;
```

%% Format string for each line of text:

```
formatSpec = '%f%s%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';
```

%% Open the text file.

```
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
```

%% Read columns of data according to format string.

```
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
```

%% Close the text file.

```
fclose(fileID);
```

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names

```
ID = dataArray{:, 1};
Date = dataArray{:, 2};
X = dataArray{:, 3};
Y = dataArray{:, 4};
Z = dataArray{:, 5};
```

%% Clear temporary variables

```
clearvars filename delimiter startRow formatSpec fileID dataArray ans;
```

%% Alternatively, you could import the data by using one line of code:

%  (1) Save your file as an Excel file (.xlsx)

%  (2) Use readtable to import the file

```
data = readtable('saved_excel_file.xlsx');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I tried the code, the output X is only a 1*1 double, whose value is 0.0104........

Comment: Hi, did you check that your file is in the format you indicated? I validated the code with your data (saved as a .csv file) and it worked fine. Also, check that you copied the entire code and possibly post your modification here.